# Influence the order of digits and characters in compare method

Tags: java, sorting

I have a Wicket web application, that sorts table rows in the following order:

Ascending:

- first characters (A-Z)
- then numbers (1-9)

Now i'm writing a webunit test to test the sorting mechanism, but it seems to switch the order of characters and numbers like:

Ascending:

- first numbers (1-9)
- then characters (A-Z)

So this code will fail, when sorting ascending and it encounters the two entries:

- ...
- ZZZ
- 111
- ...

My simplified sorting code:

```
protected int compare(String val1, String val2) {
        return val1.compareTo(val2);
}
```

What's the "java way" of telling my test code to test the order like my web application produces it?
May be something like `Collator`? I would prefer a JRE solution over a selfwritten `Comparator` over a 3rd party library.

Comment: I don't know of a built-in JRE solution.  Writing your own `Comparator` or wrapping strings is a custom `Comparable` class is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a [RuleBasedCollator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html) like this:

```
String rule = "<a,A<b,B<c,C<[...]<'1'<'2'<'3'<'4'[...]";
RuleBasedCollator collator = new RuleBasedCollator(rule);
return collator.compare(val1,val2);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. Could you edit the rule and remove the second comma after 'A'?